# Android, Google Cloud Messaging - push gets to phone, but does not create a push notification on the device

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have been trying to get Google Cloud Messaging to create push notifications. I am able to register the device, store the registration id on the server, and then send the push message back to the device.

I am able to do all these and the catLog showed that the push message got to the device. But on the device the push notification message did not appear.

What could be the cause of this?

Just in case, here is how I register the device:

```
        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this); 
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

        final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
        if (regId.equals("")) 
        {
            // Automatically registers application on startup. 
            GCMRegistrar.register(getApplicationContext(), SENDER_ID); 
        } 
        else 
        {        
            // Device is already registered on GCM, check server. 
            if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(getApplicationContext())) 
            { 
                // Not sure what to do here :)
            } 
            else 
            {
                if ( user_id != null )
                {
                    GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID); // google register         
                    setRegistrationId ( user_id , regId ); // saves id on server
                }
            }
        }
```

End on onPostExecute I do GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(getApplicationContext(), true);

Here is my onMessage() method in my GCMIntentService

```
  @Override
  protected void onMessage(Context ctxt, Intent message) {
    Bundle extras=message.getExtras();

    for (String key : extras.keySet()) {
      Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(),
            String.format("onMessage: %s=%s", key,
                          extras.getString(key)));
    }
  }
```

Is this the problem maybe? How should it actually be?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What could be the cause of this?

Here are some possibilities:

1. You do not have a `GCMIntentService` subclass in your app.
2. You do, but it is not registered in the manifest.
3. You do, but you did not override `onMessage()`
4. You did, but your `onMessage()` is not properly logging the event or otherwise letting you know that the event occurred.

Comment: I just added the onMessage() to my original question. Is is correct?

Comment: hmmm..any other thoughts on what else may be the problem? I am stuck on this for over a day now :)